No volumes for HDD in Windows Diskpart/no drive letter on reboot
Whenever I reboot my PC, one of my HDD's just decides to remove its drive letter. I think this started to happen when I installed Linux on it but wiped it after I gave up (so maybe it still thinks it's like a boot partition so defaults to hidden). I've tried messing with disk part and while the disk is listed, there aren't any volumes to maybe remove the "hidden" attribute as I saw one solution for. detail disk with the funky drive selected gives:
Type   : SATA
Status : Online
Path   : 1
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(0102)#PCI(0001)#ATA(C01T00L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

There are no volumes.

DISKPART>

This is what I'd expect a drive to show if it has no partitions but it does and I can access it in file explorer... All my files stay intact after reboots but I have to go into a 3rd party disk management tool (AOMEI Partition Assistant) to manually assign it a drive letter.

How is it formatted? Show diskmgmt.msc view.

you already format the hdd after you failed to install linux? i little hit can
disappear drives and letters, but it can restore again without loosing it try:
Method 1:
You may check in Disk Management if the capacity of that hard disk  is being listed or not.
a) Click on Start.
b) In search tab, type disk management.
c) Check if the hard disk is listed or not.
Method 2:
Run the fixit from the following link:
Hardware devices are not working
http://support.microsoft.com/mats/hardware_device_problems/en-us
Method 3:
Step 1:
Try to boot computer in Safe mode and check for both the issues.
Start your computer in safe mode
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode
